# How to recover safe info using gnosis-safe-cli

Tags: gnosis-safe, cli

[image: gnosis safe cli]

Please, how do I retrieve safe information using Gnosis-safe-cli, using the appropriate node provider?

Thanks in anticipation

[image: request data from node-provider]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was that the address was a master-copy address...
This means it's not a proper safe address